# How to set automatically BackButtonCustomize for all screen in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to customize Backbutton in flutter. And I did it.

```
AppBar(
  leading:BackButtonCustomize()
)
```

However, I want set that automatically for all screens.
How to set automatically BackButtonCustomize for all screen?

Comment: one way is to create an custom app bar and use it everywhere.

Comment: Thank you! At here I want somethings the same as  set TexStyle on ThemeData. But I don't know if flutter supports that?